# Duplicate blank Column Headers in analysis for Office

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I have a piece of code and it is bugging out on the below line the error I am getting is

> 'Run Time error 1004' method Range object Global Failed

```
DS1_C = Range("Crosstab1").Columns.Count
```

So what I am trying to achieve with the code is anywhere that I have blank column header take the preceding column header paste that into the blank column and add a 2 to differentiate so I can pivot easily

My code is below any and all help is greatly appreciated

I have also provided a picture for better understanding see pic 1

CODE

```
Sub Headers()
Dim DS1_C, DS1_R, lResult As Long

Dim DS1 As String




DS1 = "Sheet1"



lResult = Application.Run("SAPGetProperty", "IsDataSourceActive", "DS_1")

If lResult = True Then

   DS1_C = Range("Crosstab1").Columns.Count

   DS1_R = Range("Crosstab1").Rows.Count



   For i = 1 To DS1_C - 1

       If Worksheets(DS1).Range("A5").Offset(0, i + 1) = "" Then

          Worksheets(DS1).Range("A5").Offset(0, i + 1) = Worksheets(DS1).Range("A5").Offset(0, i) & "2"

       End If

   Next i

End If
End Sub
```

Pic 1

[image]

Comment: Your error suggests that the named range `Crosstab1` can't be found. Qualifying the sheet might help, but check the range exists first.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this be like

```
With Sheets("Crosstab1")
    Set DS1_C = .Range.Columns(.Columns.Count)
End With
```

Your code `DS1_C = Range("Crosstab1").Columns.Count` seems to specify a range which is an object and requires the code word "Set". To specify a column as a range the syntax is like `ActiveSheet.Columns(3)`. In your code the column number is represented by the result of `Activesheet.Columns.Count`.

You seem to have a similar error when specifying a rows range.

Answer (score 0):

**Once you're confident that the `Crosstab1` name exists:**

As per my comment, try:

```
DS1_C = Worksheets(DS1).Range("Crosstab1").Columns.Count
DS1_R = Worksheets(DS1).Range("Crosstab1").Rows.Count
```

You could also instead of referring to the DS1 variable each time, create objects to refer to with:

```
Dim DS1Sht As Worksheet
Dim CTab1 As Range
Set DS1Sht = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set CTab1 = DS1Sht.Range("Crosstab1")

DS1_C = CTab1.Columns.Count
DS1_R = CTab1.Rows.Count
```